# Getting the variance of a distribution from percentiles.

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization

There are some logs of readings every 5 minutes. The only statistics logged are the mean, 75th, 90th, 95th and 99th percentiles. I want to get an estimate of the variance of the logs. Say I want to assume the data is normally distributed (though the approach will probably extend to other distributional assumptions as well). In general, let's say the mean, $\mu$ and $q_i$th percentile, $x_i$ are given $\forall \;\;i \in 1 \dots n$. Find the best variance of the Gaussian, $\sigma^2$.

---

My attempt:

One approach I can think of is to minimize the sum of squared differences between the expected and actual percentiles. So, if $\Phi(t,\mu,\sigma)$ is the survival function of the Gaussian, we want to minimize:

$$L(\sigma) = \sum (\Phi(x_i,\mu,\sigma)-q_i)^2$$

Alternately, we could minimize:

$$M(\sigma) = \sum (\Phi^{-1}(q_i,\mu,\sigma)-x_i)^2$$

But here, we're making the arbitrary decision of minimizing the sum of squares. Is there an approach akin to maximum likelihood estimation here where we don't have to make that arbitrary choice?

Answer (score 1):

Take the quantile function of the normal distribution: $Q(p)=\newcommand{erf}{\operatorname{erf}}\mu+\sigma\sqrt2\erf^{-1}(2p-1)$. From each given percentile we get an estimate of the standard deviation $\sigma$ as
$$
x_i-\mu=Q(q_i)-\mu=\sigma\sqrt2\erf^{-1}(2q_i-1)$$
$$\sigma=\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sqrt2\erf^{-1}(2q_i-1)}$$
Repeat for each $q_i/x_i$ pair and take the average.

With a little more effort, this approach can be extended to arbitrary distributions.

Comment: @perclytaxel thanks. I think it should be $x_i-\mu$ in the numerator right? And if so, what if it becomes negative? Also what are we optimizing with this approach and why is it better than the ones I proposed?

Comment: @RohitPandey If $\sigma$ comes out negative, perhaps just replace it with its absolute value.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. And also, what is the motivation for taking a simple average? Maybe some percentiles are more reliable than others so it should be a weighed one?

Comment: @RohitPandey You can take any average for the standard deviations, like the median.